# How can I merge video files (has audio stream) and audio file (as a bgm) using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to merge video files (has audio stream) and audio file (as a background music) using ffmpeg command.

- video1.mp4 (has video and audio stream)
- video2.mp4 (has video and audio stream)
- audio.mp3 (audio stream only)

These are sample files.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ejmjmwk9j0nsk7z/AABqkYd7Zf9izRn785Vd92Wra?dl=0

I tried these command and more but all didn't work.

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex "concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" output.mp4

ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 output.mp4
```

How can I create the video like this structure in one command?

```
video channle1 | video1 video stream | video2 video stream |
audio channle1 | video1 audio stream | video2 audio stream |
audio channel2 |                   audio                   |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i video2.mp4 -i audio.mp3 \
-filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a];[a][2]amix[outa]" \
-map [v] -map [outa] output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you, Excellent! This is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with two commands:

```
ffmpeg -i 'concat:video1.mp4|video2.mp4' -codec copy output.mp4
```

and then add background audio:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental final_output.mp4
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: -strict experimental is no longer required with ffmpeg 3.2.1-1.